# Create CSR and self-signed-certificate with pyOpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, csr, pyopenssl

using pyOpenSSL I want to create

1. a key pair for self-signing
2. a certificate signing request (csr)
3. a self-signed-certificate

When I use the openSSL command line tool I used the following commands to do that:

1. a key pair for self-signing

   `openssl genrsa -out pkey.pem 2048`

   `openssl rsa -in pkey.pem -out public-pkey.pem -outform PEM -pubout`
2. a certificate signing request (csr)

   `openssl req -new -key pkey.pem -subj "/C=US/O=XXX/CN=XXX" -days 365 -out csrrequest.csr`
3. a self-signed-certificate

   `openssl x509 -in csrrequest.csr -req -signkey pkey.pem -days 365 -set_serial 0x12345 -sha256 -out selfsignedcert.pem`

**This works!** Server accepts the self-signed certificate and returns a server-signed certificate.

For pyOpenSSL I use the following code:

1. a key pair for self-signing

   `psec = crypto.PKey()`

   `psec.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)`
2. a certificate signing request (csr)

   `csrrequest = crypto.X509Req()`

   `csrrequest.get_subject().C  = "US"`

   `csrrequest.get_subject().O  = "XXX"`

   `csrrequest.get_subject().CN = "XXX"`

   `csrrequest.set_pubkey(psec)`
3. a self-signed-certificate

   `selfsignedcert = crypto.X509()`

   `selfsignedcert.set_serial_number(12345)`

   `selfsignedcert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)`

   `selfsignedcert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(365*24*60*60)`

   `selfsignedcert.set_subject(csrrequest.get_subject())`

   `selfsignedcert.set_issuer(selfsignedcert.get_subject())`

   `selfsignedcert.set_pubkey(csrrequest.get_pubkey())`

   `selfsignedcert.sign(psec, "sha256")`

**This is not working!** Server does not accept the self-signed certificate. The server is not able to sign and return a server-signed certificate.

By using pyOpenSSL, however, I miss the input of `openssl x509 -in csrrequest.csr -req` for the creation of the self-signed certificate...

Where is my fault? Does anyone know what I am doing wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: See [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store. I'm not sure how to do it with pyOpenSSL, however.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sign the CSR with the private key (similar to a self-signed certificate, but the CA will replace this signature with its own signature in the final certificate).

Try `csrrequest.sign(psec,"sha256")`

Comment: Maybe more details, please?

Comment: Excellent, works for me (error during parsing without this step)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is it that is not working ?

I noticed that the times are set wrong

Instead of :

```
selfsignedcert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)

selfsignedcert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(365*24*60*60)
```

What if you tried

```
current_ts = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())

selfsignedcert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(current_ts)

selfsignedcert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(current_ts + 365*24*60*60)
```